# Preventing deletion of items from Chrome History

Tags: mac, chrome

This might be the wrong site, but I've been thinking about ways to prevent some users at our organization from deleting entries from their history, as well as prevent them from wiping their history entirely (e.g. through clear browsing data).

These users are in a 1 to 1 program and are thus mobile, so implementing a network-level solution at my workplace wouldn't be enough to keep continuous track of what sites are being visited.

At the moment, there is no official solution from Google, the only setting relating to history is importing history from the user's default browser or preventing history from being saved entirely.

None of the solutions I've come up with are particularly elegant, usually hinging on using filesystem permissions in somewhat perverse ways (which doesn't work with Chrome's sqlite databases)

Any answers will be greatly appreciated!

(edit)

I apologize for not mentioning this initially, but all systems that will be managed are running Mac OS X 10.8. Just in case anyone has an answer that may be platform-specific.

Comment: You'd do much better to log everything at your firewall.

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't. You'd set up the network so everyone goes through a proxy server, then keep the logs to see what IP is hitting what sites.

Depending on the implementation you can have people log in, or just track by machine IP, or invisibly log the user if the proxy integrated to understand Windows and AD.

That removes the logging burden from the Windows client and instead puts it on a server in your own control.